# biblatex - apa style - need two formatting changes

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Yet another APA-style modification for biblatex, sorry folks :/

Please be gentle, I am using Latex about 10 hours now...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{GeeraertsEenzondagspakHet2001,
    langid = {dutch},
    title = {Een zondagspak? Het Nederlands in Vlaanderen: gedrag, beleid, attitudes},
    volume = {44},
    journaltitle = {Ons Erfdeel},
    date = {2001},
    pages = {337--344},
    author = {Geeraerts, Dirk}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=apa,citestyle=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

In 1988 C was totally awesome. \parencite[338]{GeeraertsEenzondagspakHet2001}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

---

I need 2 changes to the output of `\printbibliography`:

> Geeraerts, D. (2001). Een zondagspak? Het Nederlands in Vlaanderen: gedrag, beleid, attitudes. *Ons Erfdeel, 44,* 337–344.

should be

> **Geeraerts, D. (2001).** Een zondagspak? Het Nederlands in Vlaanderen: gedrag, beleid, attitudes. *Ons Erfdeel* 44, 337–344.

1. "Geeraerts, D. (2001)." needs to be bold
2. *Ons Erfdeel, 44,* 337–344. => *Ons Erfdeel* 44, 337–344.

Close observers can see that "44" is no longer in italics and has lost the **comma** in front of it.

---

I am currently using `biblatex` because my Zotero exports nicely to that format. I am on Windows 10, MikTeX 2.9.6637, and TexStudio 2.12.6.

Thank you for your help!

[I am wiling to change bib-package if needed]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I changed the references to "Harvard style" to "APA style". "Harvard style" generally refers to a specific style of the citation call-outs (aka "authoryear-style"). It looks like you're looking to modify the appearance of the formatted bib entries, not that of the citation call-outs, right?

Comment: @Mico, I have no idea what you are trying to ask from me :)

I do understand the difference between APA-style and Harvard-formatting. And I do think I need to have the 'reference' list modified as moewe did...

Does this answer your question?

Comment: So you've just confirmed my guess, which was that you were not looking to change the appearance of the citation call-outs (which might be called "harvard style").

Comment: I have made some minor changes to the \cite{} printout but those were not relevant for this particular question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `biblatex-apa`, a style that will give you full-blown APA style and not "Harvard style" (Harvard style is not a well defined term and generally means just author-year citations). If you modify anything with `biblatex-apa` your document is not APA compliant any more.

In general I would avoid heavily customised styles such as `biblatex-apa` if I do not have to follow the exact style guide that it implements. Customised styles are not designed to allow for heavy modifications, so they can be a bit harder to modify than the standard styles, which were written with the need for easy modification in mind. If the changes you need to apply to `biblatex-apa` are minute, you may get away with modifying that style. But as soon as the changes get more copious and complicated, one of the standard styles is almost always a better choice.

OK, so what did we do here?

- We modified the `author` and `editorinauthpos` macros to turn the author name and year bold. In both of these cases the only thing we did was to add `\printtext[bold]{...}` around the original definition from `apa.bbx`.
- With `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}` we made sure that the `volume` number is not italic any more.
- Finally, in the `journal+issuetitle` macro (also from `apa.bbx`) we replaced two commas by spaces to remove the comma before the `volume`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{GeeraertsEenzondagspakHet2001,
    langid = {dutch},
    title = {Een zondagspak? Het Nederlands in Vlaanderen: gedrag, beleid, attitudes},
    volume = {44},
    journaltitle = {Ons Erfdeel},
    date = {2001},
    pages = {337--344},
    author = {Geeraerts, Dirk}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=apa,citestyle=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bold}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \printtext[bold]{%
    \ifnameundef{author}
      {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
      {\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{nameaddon}%
       \ifnameundef{with}
         {}
         {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
          \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
          \setunit*{\addspace}}}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}}}

\renewbibmacro*{editorinauthpos}{%
  \printtext[bold]{%
    \global\booltrue{bbx:editorinauthpos}%
    \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}%
       % need to clear editor so we don't get an "In" clause later
       % But we also need to set a flag to say we did this so we
       % don't lose sight of the fact we once had an editor for
       % various year placement tests
       \clearname{editor}%
       \setunit{\adddot\space}%
       \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}%
       \setunit{\adddot\space}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issuename}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
In 1988 C was totally awesome. \parencite[338]{GeeraertsEenzondagspakHet2001}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, best practice is not to touch APA at all and just ask my teachers at the university if APA is good enough for them...

They will prolly not want to ditch the harvard-formatting (not style), given the 70-somehting document they wrote about it... 

Your modifications seem to be bang on. I will test them tomorrow (at home now). Could you please elaborate on your latex-fu? How on earth does one begin to write modifications like you did...?

Comment: @LooselySubtle Asking if your teachers can accept other styles is always worth a try. I've always dealt with very sensible lecturers that accepted any bibliography/citation style that was consistent and complete. But if your lecturers are adamant and insist on a particular style, then you will have to try to implement that for better or worse. In that case it is often better to start from one of `biblatex`'s standard styles instead of a heavily modified custom style such as `biblatex-apa` or `biblatex-chicago`. ...

Comment: ...  But that is a judgement call. If the styles already get you very far and the expected modifications are not that complicated, starting from a custom style is of course acceptable. Of course you can't always tell from the outset whether or not the modifications will be simple. A good primer for `biblatex` customisations is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864. You'll find thousands of questions on this site that can give you an idea of how one does these things.

Comment: Unless you're working in psychology or related social science fields, APA style usually means "some version of author-year" and doesn't really mean full blown APA style. And if you require special formatting different from the proper APA format, then it's likely that this is how the term "APA style" is being used by your teachers. It's usually in contrast to, e.g. MLA style which is the one commonly taught in high schools (at least in N. America) where writing is usually taught in the context of literature not science.

Comment: @moewe, I would like to take up your advice and omit style=apa so I can start from biblatex's standard styles. 

Where do you find those macro's and FieldFormats for copy/pasting and editing?

Comment: @LooselySubtle If the modifications you have requested are all that you need, then you can stick to APA style and my answer. Modifying the standard styles mean more work, if you want them to look like APA. If you already have what you need, why should you do more work than necessary? If you start a new project or if you need to do more changes, however, it can be a good idea to switch over to the standard styles. ...

Comment: ... The generic standard macros live in files called `standard.bbx` and `biblatex.def`. The style-specific citation macros live in a file called `<style>.cbx`, those for the bibliography in `<style>.bbx`. So for `authoryear-ibid` you'd have to look at `authoryear-ibid.cbx` and `authoryear-ibid.bbx`. If you don't know where to find these files, type `kpsewhich standard.bbx` in your command line and the path to that file will be returned. They should be in `tex/latex/biblatex` of your TeX tree. On my system that's `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex`

Comment: @LooselySubtle Let me know what you went with in the end.

Comment: @moewe, a little bit of column a, a little bit of column B. My teacher gave me leave to use "a style as close to ours" because of latex and zotero. But since I will have to write many many papers in the coming years, I opted for default author-year and will be (trying to) create(ing) my own Harvard-style "as close to theirs". Because they are mainly looking for consistency when citing and referencing... You all can expect many more questions in the months to come :) But I know this beautiful community will be as helpful as ever...